# Can i Integrate Google Hangout for online lessons in website?

Tags: php, codeigniter, video-streaming, live-streaming, google-hangouts

I am developing a website using CodeIgniter and i want to integrate live video streaming functionality in the website.

The admin will provide online lessons and the users who have purchased the online lessons will have access to the video lesson via a one to many video streaming feature at a particular time. After the tutorial is over, the video will be saved in the user's dashboard for future use. Can this be achieved using Google hangout?

Or please let me know if there is any other better option for the same.

Comment: There's [BigBlueButton](http://bigbluebutton.org/overview/). You can find CodeIgniter wrappers.